# Exercise involving Turan's theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**Theorem 1**

$\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n^2}{2|E(G)| + n}$

where $\alpha(G)$ stands for the largest independent set of vertices in the graph $G$.

*Using **theorem 1** prove that any graph on $n$ vertices with no triangles has at most $n^2/4$ edges.*

I looked up an alternative formulation of the theorem up on Wikipedia, which gives the answer easily by giving the upper bound on edges if the graph G is  $K_{r+1}$-free, using that the exercise becomes trivial.

However, I cannot see how to solve it with from **Theorem 1**. I know that if we were to consider the complement of $G$ the largest clique would be of the same size as the largest independent set. But a triangle needn't be the largest clique, furthermore, a complement graph of a triangle-free graph needn't include a triangle.
I cannot see the relationship between being triangle-free and the size of the largest clique/independent set.

Any hints would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is a triangle-free graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, then the largest clique in $G$ has size at most $2$. Therefore, $\alpha(\bar{G})\leq 2$, where $\bar{G}$ is the complement of $G$. So **Theorem 1** applied to $\bar{G}$ gives $$2\geq \alpha(\bar{G}) \geq \frac{n^2}{2\left({n\choose 2}-m\right)+n}.$$ You can finish it from here I trust.