Dual version of Turan's theorem
Theorem 1
$G$ is of order $n$, then $\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n^2}{2|E(G)| + n}$
where $\alpha(G)$ stands for the largest independent set in the graph $G$.
Using theorem 1, we can prove that any graph on $n$ vertices with no triangles has at most $n^2/4$ edges. (Turan's theorem)
See for example @MISC {
URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1110558}
}
My question is can we prove Theorem 1 using (Turan's theorem)? I only find proof of theorem 1 using probabilistic method. See https://sarielhp.org/misc/blog/08/11/19/turan2.pdf

I think you need a general version of your version of Turán's theorem i.e.
Any graph $G$ which does not contain $K_{r+1}$ as a subgraph has at most as many edges as the Turán graph $T(n,r)$. For a fixed value of $r$, this graph has $$\left(1-\frac{1}{r}+o(1)\right) \frac{n^2}{2}$$ edges.
Unless I'm mistaken ,what you call Turán's Theorem is the above theorem with $r=2$.
How to use the above theorem to prove your Theorem 1 one can be seen here.
Therefore don't think there is a direct way to prove Theorem 1 using your Turán's Theorem.
